# Putting Results of for loop into a data frame in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a function that will return a numeric class object, here is a simplified version:

```
count.matches <- function(x) {
  ifelse(!is.na(a[,x] & a[,2]),1,0)
}
```

it just produces an object of 0s and 1s.
For example

```
count.matches(4)
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

I just want to do a simple for loop of this function and store the results in a data frame, i.e. each time the function loops through create a column, however I am having trouble.

```
p <- data.frame()
my.matches <- for(i in 2:100) { 
  p[i,] <- count.matches(i)
 }
```

This produces nothing. Sorry if this is a really stupid question, but I have tried a bunch of things and nothing seems to work. If you need any more information, please let me know and I will provide it.

Comment: What does a look like?

Comment: Don't grow data frames (r objects in general) within loops. This is highly inefficient!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for` does not return the last value in the loop and combine the results. It returns `NULL`.

Using `for` you will have to create the `data.frame` first, and fill it with the results:

```
my.matches <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow(a), ncol(a) - 1))
for (i in 2:100) {
  my.matches[,i] <- count.matches(i)
}
```

Alternative you could use the `foreach` package, which provides the functionality you're expecting from `for`.

```
library(foreach)
my.matches <- foreach(i = 2:100, .combine=data.frame) %do% {
  count.matches(i)
}
```

Comment: Hey, don't know why you got downvoted, that worked perfectly. Thanks a ton for the help, and thanks for the suggestion of the other package, I will probably be using it, as it seems more intuitive.

Comment: You're welcome! Just be careful with the differences in syntax between `for` and `foreach`, I've been tripped up many times!