# R Loop to subset large data frame and give multiple row output

Tags: r, loops, subset

Following up from a question I asked yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425847/r-subset-data-frame-based-on-multiple-values-for-multiple-variables), I am trying to design a loop that will subset events from data `df1` based on unique combinations of matching date, time, and ID in a second dataset `df2`. The output for each iteration will be multiple rows long, and each iteration will have either differing numbers of rows, or might be empty. In the end I need to combine all the iteration outputs into 1 data frame that show the dates, times, and ID numbers for each event on each date. Allocating an empty matrix and running a regular FOR loop or nested loop isn't getting me anywhere. I don't know if I need to start with a different type of structure, or if my dimensions are wrong. Maybe there is an easier way all together.

Here is a sample of the data structure (although the original data is much longer).

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(Date = c("12-31-2008", "12-31-2008", "12-31-2008", 
"12-31-2008", "12-31-2008", "12-31-2008", "01-01-2009", "01-01-2009", 
"01-01-2009", "01-01-2009", "01-10-2009", "01-10-2009", "01-10-2009", 
"01-10-2009", "01-10-2009", "01-10-2009", "01-10-2009", "01-10-2009", 
"01-10-2009", "01-10-2009", "01-10-2009", "01-10-2009", "01-10-2009", 
"01-10-2009", "01-10-2009", "01-10-2009", "01-10-2009", "01-10-2009", 
"01-10-2009", "01-11-2009", "01-11-2009", "01-17-2009", "01-17-2009", 
"01-18-2009", "01-18-2009", "01-18-2009", "01-18-2009", "01-18-2009", 
"01-18-2009", "01-18-2009", "01-18-2009", "01-18-2009", "01-18-2009", 
"01-18-2009", "01-18-2009", "01-19-2009", "01-19-2009", "01-19-2009", 
"01-19-2009", "01-19-2009"), IDNum = c("534198", "534198", "534198", 
"534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", 
"534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", 
"534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", 
"534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", 
"534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", 
"534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", 
"534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198"), Time = c("19:01", 
"19:53", "20:55", "22:03", "23:04", "23:55", "00:45", "01:48", 
"02:50", "03:50", "02:35", "03:42", "04:49", "05:53", "06:55", 
"07:55", "08:43", "10:23", "10:31", "11:41", "15:27", "16:33", 
"17:41", "18:46", "19:46", "20:48", "21:48", "22:48", "23:48", 
"01:49", "02:49", "21:49", "22:49", "12:04", "13:04", "15:05", 
"16:05", "17:05", "18:07", "18:49", "19:49", "20:49", "21:49", 
"22:50", "23:50", "00:50", "01:50", "03:02", "04:22", "05:25"
)), .Names = c("Date", "IDNum", "Time"), row.names = 8643:8692, class = "data.frame")

dput(df2)
structure(list(Date = c("01-04-2009", "01-05-2009", "01-05-2009", 
"01-06-2009", "01-06-2009", "01-07-2009", "01-07-2009", "01-08-2009", 
"01-08-2009", "01-09-2009", "01-09-2009", "01-10-2009", "01-11-2009", 
"01-12-2009", "01-12-2009", "01-13-2009", "01-14-2009", "01-14-2009", 
"01-21-2009", "01-21-2009", "01-22-2009", "01-22-2009", "01-23-2009", 
"01-23-2009", "01-24-2009", "01-24-2009", "01-25-2009", "01-25-2009", 
"01-26-2009", "01-26-2009", "01-27-2009", "01-28-2009", "01-28-2009", 
"01-28-2009", "01-28-2009", "01-29-2009", "01-29-2009", "01-29-2009", 
"01-29-2009", "02-05-2009", "02-05-2009", "02-05-2009", "02-06-2009", 
"02-06-2009", "02-06-2009", "02-07-2009", "02-07-2009", "02-07-2009", 
"02-08-2009", "02-08-2009"), IDNum = c("599091", "599091", "599091", 
"599091", "599091", "599091", "599091", "599091", "599091", "599091", 
"599091", "599091", "599091", "599091", "599091", "599091", "599091", 
"599091", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", 
"534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", "534198", 
"697345", "697345", "534198", "534198", "697345", "697345", "697345", 
"534198", "697345", "697345", "697345", "697345", "697345", "697345", 
"697345", "697345", "697345", "697345", "697345"), Trip = c("GL0229", 
"GL0229", "GL0229", "GL0229", "GL0229", "GL0229", "GL0229", "GL0229", 
"GL0229", "GL0229", "GL0229", "GL0229", "GL0229", "GL0229", "GL0229", 
"GL0229", "GL0229", "GL0229", "GL0230", "GL0230", "GL0230", "GL0230", 
"GL0230", "GL0230", "GL0230", "GL0230", "GL0230", "GL0230", "GL0230", 
"GL0230", "GL0230", "GL0233", "GL0233", "GL0230", "GL0230", "GL0233", 
"GL0233", "GL0233", "GL0230", "GL0234", "GL0234", "GL0234", "GL0234", 
"GL0234", "GL0234", "GL0234", "GL0234", "GL0234", "GL0234", "GL0234"
), Replicate = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 14L, 15L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 16L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), Start = c("12:00", 
"08:35", "15:33", "08:30", "15:51", "10:02", "23:04", "11:17", 
"21:31", "11:16", "20:07", "11:28", "07:37", "08:40", "16:32", 
"09:14", "08:04", "15:15", "07:16", "16:17", "07:10", "16:40", 
"07:00", "16:25", "07:17", "16:50", "07:20", "16:18", "07:20", 
"15:40", "07:10", "09:34", "11:07", "07:55", "16:38", "07:01", 
"08:26", "14:47", "07:18", "07:47", "09:17", "14:58", "07:48", 
"08:59", "14:53", "07:30", "09:12", "13:47", "08:56", "09:53"
), End = c("17:21", "15:08", "22:44", "15:12", "09:06", "19:16", 
"10:28", "20:12", "10:14", "18:48", "10:53", "20:23", "14:07", 
"15:02", "22:27", "18:03", "15:07", "21:19", "16:04", "22:04", 
"16:31", "23:01", "16:15", "22:07", "16:33", "22:37", "16:05", 
"22:17", "15:22", "22:31", "16:05", "16:41", "19:01", "16:20", 
"21:56", "14:31", "19:46", "00:30", "15:10", "14:21", "19:27", 
"23:45", "14:31", "19:20", "23:05", "14:51", "20:15", "00:17", 
"14:31", "18:07")), .Names = c("Date", "IDNum", "Trip", "Replicate", 
"Start", "End"), row.names = 506:555, class = "data.frame")
```

First I found the dates that match between the 2 data sets and created a new variable `records` to display information from `df2` based on the matching dates. In this example, I'm just using the 2nd matching date:

```
match_dates <- as.character(intersect(df1$Date, df2$Date))
records <- df2[which(df2$Date == match_dates[2]),]
print(records)

          Date  IDNum   Trip Replicate Start   End
518 01-11-2009 599091 GL0229        13 07:37 14:07
```

In the original much larger data set, `records` ends up being something more like this:

```
records <- df2[which(df2$Date == match_dates[25]),]
print(records)
#           Date  IDNum   Trip Replicate Start   End
# 659 04-02-2009 507646 GL0247        10 09:43 05:19
# 660 04-02-2009 680845 GL0249         4 05:37 11:29
# 661 04-02-2009 680845 GL0249         5 11:59 16:47
```

The event(s) of interest for each iteration of `records` is then defined as `df1` times between `Start` and `End` like this (I did it this way to preserve the unique combinations of date-time-ID-replicate):

```
event1 <- subset(df1, Date==records[1,"Date"] & IDNum==records[1,"IDNum"] & Time >= records[1,"Start"] & Time <= records[1,"End"])
event2 <- subset(df1, Date==records[2,"Date"] & IDNum==records[2,"IDNum"] & Time >= records[2,"Start"] & Time <= records[2,"End"])
event3 <- subset(df1, Date==records[3,"Date"] & IDNum==records[3,"IDNum"] & Time >= records[3,"Start"] & Time <= records[3,"End"])
```

The results for each of these events looks like this:

```
print(event1) #This result is empty
    [1] NewRecNum Date      IDNum     Time      Speed    
    <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

print(event2)
            Date  IDNum  Time
80620 04-02-2009 680845 06:35
80621 04-02-2009 680845 07:35
80622 04-02-2009 680845 08:35
80623 04-02-2009 680845 09:35
80624 04-02-2009 680845 10:35

print(event3)
                    Date  IDNum  Time
        80626 04-02-2009 680845 12:35
        80627 04-02-2009 680845 13:35
        80628 04-02-2009 680845 14:35
        80629 04-02-2009 680845 15:35
        80630 04-02-2009 680845 16:35
```

I'm aiming for a loop that will take every instance of matching dates from `match_dates` (in this case 147), create 147 corresponding `records` from `df2`, and then use the Date, IDNum, Start, and End times in each `records` to subset `df1` and output the `df1` events. What I have so far (that isn't working):

```
records <- matrix(ncol=6, nrow=nrow(df1)) # Create an empty matrix to start
event=NULL
for (i in 1:length(match_dates)) 
    { records[i] <- df2[which(df2$Date == match_dates[i]), ]

    for (j in 1:nrow(records[i]))
    { event[j] <- subset(df1, Date==records[i,"Date"] & IDNum==records[i,"IDNum"] & Time >= records[i,"Start"] & Time <= records[i,"End"])
      }
}
print(event)

Error in 1:nrow(records[i]) : argument of length 0
In addition: Warning message:
In records[i] <- df2[which(df2$Date == match_dates[i]), ] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> print(event)
NULL
```

Thanks in advance for any help! I'm banging my head against the wall on this.

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

I changed `records` to

```
records <- subset(df2, Date %in% df1$Date)
```

Then wrote a function to subset the matching rows from `df1` as

```
event_func <- function(df,records,i){
  event_int <- subset(df, Date==records[i,"Date"] & IDNum==records[i,"IDNum"] & Time >= records[i,"Start"] & Time <= records[i,"End"])
  return(event_int)
}
```

This function works, and outputs what I need. But I'm still having trouble with a loop that will take the 686 rows of `records`, match them to `df1`, and output a final data frame of all the `df1` rows that match. I also tried using `lapply` Here's what I have (neither of which is working):

```
# First option using a loop
final <- data.frame()
event_int <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:nrow(records)) {
  event_int[i] <- event_func(df1, records,i)
  final <- rbind(event_int, event_int[i])
}

# Second option using lapply
lapply(records, event_func(df1,records,1:nrow(records)))
```

Thanks again for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got something to work! I ended up changing a bit of the original coding and found a really helpful answer for the loop from another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776430/putting-results-of-for-loop-into-a-data-frame-in-r).

1) I defined `records` first by matching ID and Date between `df1` and `df2`

```
records <- subset(df1, IDNum %in% df2$IDNum)
records <- subset(records, Date %in% df2$Date)

# Records looks like:
head(records,5)
               Date  IDNum  Time    Speed
    8653 01-10-2009 534198 02:35 4.001809
    8654 01-10-2009 534198 03:42 4.117383
    8655 01-10-2009 534198 04:49 4.263277
    8656 01-10-2009 534198 05:53 4.310865
    8657 01-10-2009 534198 06:55 4.353049

# df2 looks like:
head(df2)
          Date  IDNum   Trip Replicate Start   End
506 01-04-2009 599091 GL0229         1 12:00 17:21
507 01-05-2009 599091 GL0229         2 08:35 15:08
508 01-05-2009 599091 GL0229         3 15:33 22:44
509 01-06-2009 599091 GL0229         4 08:30 15:12
510 01-06-2009 599091 GL0229         5 15:51 09:06
511 01-07-2009 599091 GL0229         6 10:02 19:16
```

2) My function for subsetting `records` based on matching ID, Date, and Time with `df2`:

```
event_func <- function(i,...) {
  event_int <- subset(records, Date==df2[i,"Date"] & IDNum==df2[i,"IDNum"] & Time >= df2[i,"Start"] & Time <= df2[i,"End"])
  output <- event_int
  return(output)
}

# For example, subsetting records based on the first row of df2
event_func(1)
            Date  IDNum  Time    Speed
38613 01-04-2009 599091 12:24 1.611527
38614 01-04-2009 599091 15:58 1.545299
38615 01-04-2009 599091 17:02 1.527205
```

3) I repeated the `event_func` over all 686 rows of `df2` and put the results into a single data frame using the `foreach` package.

```
library(foreach)
final.match <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(df2), .combine=rbind) %do% {
  event_func(i)}
```

The output for `final.match` was a single data frame with 4 columns and 1634 rows, which was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here.

- `records[i]` is incorrect, if you want to assign to a row you need `records[i,]`
- `df2[which(df2$Date == match_dates[i]),]` is not guaranteed to be of any particular size and by assigning it in a loop to `records[i,]` you're making assumptions about it's size. You could assign an intermediate value and put that into `records` using yet another loop or better yet use the `rbind` function each iteration of the loop which would remove the need to pre-assign the size of `records`
- Attempting to assign a data.frame (`df2`) to a matrix (`records`) without doing any conversion is asking for trouble. `records` should probably be a data.frame here anyway.

A much simpler way of doing it is to use the [match()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) function via the %in% interface as so

```
records <- subset(df2,Date %in% df1$Date)
```

Comment: Thanks @NGaffney this was a much nicer way to make records, and gave me all the values I needed. But could you give an example of assigning an intermediate value with a loop to put into records?

Comment: I updated code in original question above, but am still having trouble with the loop and writing to a final data frame.